# Explain what a <div> tag is to a non-programmer

Tags: html, markup

So my brother is home for the holidays, and he is trying to learn HTML & Javascript.  I've had some success explaining to him many of the concepts related to this.  Most of the tags are pretty self explanatory, but I've struggled with describing a **div** tag.

To be honest, I never really got a good description for myself, just through experience I know when to use one.

A good answer will not need to include the definition of "block element" or any other technical jargon, although you can assume some basic knowledge of some HTML tags

Comment: It's an arbitrary <strong>div</strong>ision of content. It doesn't mean much by itself. If he's learned CSS, it might be more obvious why `div`s are useful.

Comment: Can it include the definition of just... "element"? Basic HTML knowledge should have that covered. (Note that tags and elements are not the same thing.)

Comment: You have not shared what your *concrete* problem is to explain it to him. Where did you hit the road block? What was he not able to understand exactly?

Comment: I sometimes describe it as a transparent plastic bag which can contain stuff as well as be painted, stretched etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For some reason the purpose or logic around the `<div> </div>` tags, made sense to me looking at **cloth clips**, and the reason it is because:

- Cloth clips are usually or almost always are applied **Two** for
  each type of cloth.*`(<div> </div>)`*
- One can not work without the other, otherwise the cloth will fall. 
  ex: *`<div>`* alone can not work.
- The purpose of them is so that, they can hold a block of code *ex*: *(a
  cloth in this case)*
- And control the structure, space, width, layout of a given object as
  per your desire.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> The  tag is nothing more than a container unit that encapsulates
>   other page elements and divides the HTML document into sections. Web
>   developers use  elements to group together HTML elements and
>   apply CSS styles to many elements at once. For instance, by wrapping a
>   set of paragraph elements into a  element, the developer can take
>   advantage of CSS styles and apply a font to all paragraphs at once by
>   applying a font style to the  tag instead of coding the same
>   style for each paragraph element.

Taken from http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmldiv.php

I think to be honest wikipedia proves a very simple explanation.

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Div_tag

Comment: lots of programming terms. OP wanted non-programming definition.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [W3's specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) are quite approachable:

> The div element has no special meaning at all. It represents its
>   children. It can be used with the class, lang, and title attributes to
>   mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements.
>
> *Note: Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element of last resort, for when no other element is suitable. Use of
>   more appropriate elements instead of the div element leads to better
>   accessibility for readers and easier maintainability for authors.*

Comment: I think the second paragraph describes it pretty well...It almost makes it sound like its discouraged to use though, and I use plenty of them!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bucket. You can put pretty much anything you want in it.

Answer (score 2):

You said you explained already the `<body>` tag. The `<div>` tag is similar, only for a part of the `<body>`. You can use it to create a division - as the tags' name says.

```
<body title="document">
  <h2 title="headline">Headline</h2>
  <div title="first-division">
    <p>
      First Paragraph...
    </p>
    <p>
      Second Paragraph...
    </p>
    <p>
      Third Paragraph...
    </p>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <address>+18 27 16 55 83 22 12</address>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**My definition of a div tag:** a separation of content for organization, ease of access, and ease of styling (CSS).

Just tell him that it's basically used as a division (**div**-ision) from the rest of the code. As Waleed Khan said in a comment above, id he understands CSS he will understand  better, as is used a lot when styling.

As you said, it is fairly hard to explain. You just learn how to use it. I would:

- Show him a few examples of how it makes styling easier.
- Show him a working, running webpage using  tags.
- Let him try to do something with is on his own, and show him how  tags are usually structured inside one another.

Comment: Not a *non-programmer* explanation

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im But he isn't a complete non-programmer...

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` and `</div>` tags along with the tags inside of them consist of a group, separated from other groups by linefeed. The group may have its own name or id in order to apply some styles on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>` tag starts a `div` element.

Comment: This is about as far as I could get explaining it too...:/

Comment: @Jameo, that’s all there is to explain about the `<div>` tag. The `div` element is a bit more complicated, but it’s really just a way mark something as an element so that it can be handled as a unit, in styling or in scripting. It differs from `span` so that by default, a `div` element starts on a new line and the content after it starts on a new line.